# A surjective map for an injective map on itself

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let $A$ be a set and $f:A\rightarrow A$ an injective map. Suppose $f(A) \subseteq C \subseteq A$, then prove that there is a surjective map from $C$ onto $A$.

I wanted to know if my proof is correct.

Suppose not. That is $\forall $ functions $g:C\rightarrow A \; \; \exists \; a\in A$ such that $g(c)\neq a$ for any $c\in C$.
Let $g$ be a restriction on $f(A)$ that is $g|_{f(A)} = a \; \forall \; a$ such that $f(a)$ exists. But this means that every element in $C\backslash f(A)$ must also have an image in A. Therefore there are multiple $c\in C$ such that $g(c)=a$ for some $a\in A$. Which is a contradiction. Thus, $g$ is surjective, proving my claim.

Comment: @Irish Debbarma "But this means that some element in $C\backslash f(A)$ must also have an image in $A$" why is that?

Comment: @Alexdanut for g to be a function every element in C will have almost 1 image, right

Comment: Well as $f$ is injective then for each $c \in C$ $f^{-1}(c) = \{a\in A| f(a) = c\}$ is non-empty.  If you have the axiom of choice you just pick one of them and all it $a_c$.  THen $g:C\to A$ via $g(c) = a_c$.  This is surjective as for all $a\in A$ there is $c_a = f(a)\in f(A)\subset C$ so $g(c_a) = a$.  But this argument *does* require AOC.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused by your wording. Why do you think that it is mandatory to have $g(c)=a$ for some $c$ (where $a$ is that element that you fixed at the beginning)? Your function $g$ may as well just fix all the elements of $C \setminus f(A)$.

Comment: @Alexdanut My wording is the issue, I agree. The a at the beginning and the a at the end need not be necessarily same. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The result follows directly from the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), but perhaps it has an easier proof

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitely construct such a surjective function. Your function $f$ gives you a bijection between $A$ and $f(A)$ (this happens because $f$ is injective). Let's call this bijection $g$. We now consider the function $h:C\to A$, $h(c)=\begin{cases}
g^{-1}(c), & c\in f(A)\\
a, & c\in C\setminus f(A)
\end{cases}$, where $a\in A$ is arbitrarily fixed. This function is clearly surjective and we are done.
Please note that this is essentially the argument that fleablood tried to give in the comments.

Comment: This is what I did in my solution. I was confused how to write it down. Thank you @Alexdanut